# Facebook shared w/o permission?

Tags: criminal-law

Somebody sent a Facebook post I made to my employer without my permission. Grant it I didn’t set any privacy settings. Can I sue for anything?

Comment: Did you suffer any kind of loss? Was anything you said not true?

Comment: No monetary loss or anything. Maybe my reputation though

Answer (score 3):

> without my permission

... is just not true - you granted permission for your posts to be forwarded, subject to the privacy settings you set, when you agreed to Facebook’s [terms](https://m.facebook.com/terms.php). Specifically 3.3.